# Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable (car::Boot package)

Tags: r

I understand the "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" error can occur when trying to subset a function or trying to access a function using `$`.  However, this is not the case in my code as you'll see in the reprex below.  I have diagnosed the issue to the fact that, for some reason, building a linear model using a formula stored in a formula object will cause `car::Boot` to generate the "subsettable error" when calling the linear model in the `object` argument.

```
library(car)
library(purrr)
library(boot)

set.seed(111)
## Reprex - Working
train_df1 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10, mean = 10, sd = 2))
train_df1$x <- train_df1$y*1.5

train_df2 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(5, mean = 10, sd = 3))
train_df2$x <- train_df2$y*1.75
train_list <- list(train_df1, train_df2)

models_list <- train_list %>%
  map(~lm(y ~ x, data = .))
car::Boot(object = models_list[[1]])    ## works fine

## Reprex - Not Working
n <- colnames(train_df1)
n <- trimws(n, "both")
f <- as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(n[!n %in% "y"], collapse = " + ")))

models_list <- train_list %>%
  map(~lm(f, data = .))               ## error is due to using the "f" formula object instead of lm(y ~ x, data = .)

car::Boot(object = models_list[[1]]) ## error occurs here
#Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

car::Boot(object = models_list[[2]])
#Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

out <- models_list[[1]]
car::Boot(object = out)
#Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: The error occurs when I run the`car::Boot` lines.  That's where I'm having the issue.  I retried the code in an empty environment with only `purrr` loaded and it's still giving the `subsettable` error.

Comment: I see where your confusion is.  In the `## error as a result of...` comment line, I was merely pointing out the fact that the error results from using the `f` formula object in place of the `lm(y ~ x, data = .)` syntax.  The `models_list` is generated fine and the error still persists when I try to bootstrap the models contained in `models_list`.  Anyways, I appreciate your input.

Comment: What version of R are you using? I am getting a different error.

Comment: I'm using R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23).

Comment: Can you try on R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)?